# Varivel Global em C

Tags: c, global, extern

Boa tarde,

Preciso usar uma variável global que depende de uma condição em um código.

Tenho os seguintes documentos Code2.cpp e Code3.cpp, ambos contém o Code1.h.

Eu declarei um extern em Code1.h:

```
extern int VARGLOBAL;
```

E no Code2.cpp eu declarei a variável:

```
in VARGLOBAL = 0;
```

Porém eu tenho um Case aqui no Code2, que pode mudar essa VARGLOBAL.

```
Case XXXX:
VARGLOBAL = 1;
break;
```

E no Code3.cpp eu tenho uma condição:

```
If ( VARGLOBAL == 1)

(faca 1)

else

(faca 2)
```

Ai que vem a dúvida, a minha VARGLOBAL sempre é "0" e entra na condicao "else" (faca 2), mesmo o Case acontecendo (tenho certeza que ele aconteceu).

O que devo fazer? Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Olá @Willian Henrique seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Seja mais específico e detalhista na sua pergunta, nos dê um exemplo reprodutível do seu código para podermos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Provavelmente não precisa disto e o erro é outro, mesmo que não seja isto, não temos como saber porque falta muita informação.

Comment: Olá, obrigado! Não sei como ser mais especifico :/ Mas, falando de outra forma, eu tenho um projeto, que tem esses Code3.cpp, code2.cpp e code1.h. Para se usar uma variavel global eu defini ela neste code1.h pois os dois arquivos cpp possuem elas inclusas. No code2 eu defini ela como 0, porem, tem um case que executa, as vezes que eu queria que mudasse a variavel de 0 para 1. Porem isso nao acontece. O case executa e a variavel global continua sendo 0, conforme definido anteriormente.